# Convert Field Type to the corresponding instance type

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class, in which I have a field called say `batman`

```
String batman
```

And I have method in this class, which does the following:

```
for(Field field : obj.getClass().getFields()) {
         if(field.getName().equals(fieldName)) // here fieldName is batman
             //now need to call Strings method like split etc
}
```

I need to convert the `field` to `String` and call methods. Is it possible to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all u can use `Field batmanField = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);` instead foreach. For get field value u can use `String batmanValue = batmanField.get(obj);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Field#get(Object obj)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get(java.lang.Object)) method to get the value of the field represented by the `Field` you are working with, on the specified object `obj`.

```
if (field.getName().equals(fieldName)) {
    String batmanValue = (String) field.get(obj);
    ..
}
```

This will give you the value of the `batman` field. Then you can use the `String` specific methods.